# populate a button from coredata

Tags: core-data, swift, nsfetchrequest

I’m spending lots of time trying to figure this out and getting no where.

I have an entity with a NSDate attribute, which successfully saves.

How on Earth do I fetch the NSDate from the store(year only section) and make it populate the text on a button.
so the button can be pressed later and taken to another View Controller/Table View Controller.

I have spent hours trying to figure this out, I’m totally stuck can’t find any examples.

Does anyone have the time to help with this please.
Using Swift
(hopefully I have formated this question correctly, bit of a noob here)
Thank you for looking

```
//year button
@IBAction func btnYear(sender: AnyObject) {

  //APP DEL REFERANCE
  var appdel: AppDelegate = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate)
  var context: NSManagedObjectContext = appdel.managedObjectContext!
  let ent = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("FilmInfo", inManagedObjectContext: context)!

  // fetch request
  var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "FilmInfo")
  request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, get the date from your data.

```
object.date
```

Then, format it so you can display it on the button.

```
var formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle= .ShortStyle 
let buttonTitle = formatter.stringFromDate(object.date)
```

Finally assign the title to the button

```
button.setTitle(buttonTitle, forState: .Normal)
```

To get to the object in the first place, fetch it. Don't forget to **execute** your fetch request.

```
var request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "FilmInfo")
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format:"id = %@", aFilmInfoID) // example
request.fetchLimit = 1
let results = context.executeFetchRequest(request, error:nil)! as [FilmInfo]
let object = results.first!
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but its not dumbed down enough.

Comment: There is nothing else to say. I cannot imagine making it any dumber. It is a perfect answer to your question, so you should accept it or at least up-vote it until you get your stuff together. - One point to note is that it is much simpler than doing a fetch request. But simple is not the same as dumb.

Comment: I added a simple fetch request for your object as an example. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help with this, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute your fetch request in your context.

```
var resultsArray = context.executeFetchRequest(request,nil)
if let arr = resultsArray {
    //we have some results
    var firstObject: FilmInfo = arr[0] as FilmInfo
    var date = firstObject.date
}
```

If you are interested in only one object you can always set `request.fetchLimit = 1`

Getting more advanced you can also fetch only the date property:

```
fetch.propertiesToFetch = ["date"]
fetch.resultType = .DictionaryResultType
```